# How keyword "const" work?

Tags: c++, constants

```
namespace pairDemo{

template<typename L, typename R>
class pair{
public:

    pair(const L& left,const R& right)
        :lft(left),rht(right)
    {
    }

    pair(const pair<L,R>& p)
        :lft(p.lft),rht(p.rht)
    {
    }

    L left() const{
        return lft;
    }
    R right() const{
        return rht;
    }

    void left(const L& left){
        lft = left;
    }
    void right(const R& right){
        rht = right;
    }
private:
    L lft;
    R rht;
};
}
```

//---------------------------------------------------

```
#include "pairTemp.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

pairDemo::pair<int, double> func(int x, double y){
    pairDemo::pair<int, double> temp(x*2, x+y);
    return temp;
}

int main(){
    int x = 2; double y = 3.55;
    pairDemo::pair<int, double> myPair = func(x,y);
    cout << myPair.left() << myPair.right();
}
```

I have a question that the constructor arguments, If I do not declare "const", the function func() will have a error. I dont why, and anyone can help me out.

Comment: If you do not declare what `const`? And the error you get is...?

Comment: Where are you not declaring const, what is the error, and on what line is that error?

Comment: The "const" in constructor arguments. if I don't delcare, the func() will have a error that it can not convert int to int&. Now I know the temporary should use const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `const`s from the constructor `pair::pair(const L& left,const R& right)` then the code `pairDemo::pair<int, double> temp(x*2, x+y);` won't work because the result of `x*2` is prohibited from binding to `L& left` and `x+y` is prohibited from binding to `R& right`.

C++ has this rule because the designers felt that function parameters of non-const reference types should indicate that the the function can change the value, and that that change should be visible to the caller.

consider:

```
void foo(int &i) {
    i = 3;
}

foo(x); // sets x to 3
foo(1); // sets 1 to 3??? prohibited
```

This could cause confusion if someone accidentally calls `foo` with a temporary like `1` or or `x+y` or `x*2`, so C++ decides to do the safe thing and not allow these to compile.

C++11 adds 'rvalue references' which have some different rules.

```
void bar(int &&i) { // && means 'rvalue reference' 
    i = 3;
}

bar(1); // sets 1 to 3!
bar(x); // prohibited.
```

rvalue references are supposed to mean that the function is getting a temporary value and whatever it does with it will not affect the outside world. Now the danger is that a function taking an rvalue reference would accidentally be called with a non-temporary. Therefore the rules try to prohibit you from passing in a non-temporary value like `x`.

Comment: Now I know the temporary should use const.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are passing x*2 and x+y to the constructor, the references must be declared as const (ie read-only).

If you are passing a non-const (ie read-write) reference, then the code of the function would be able to modify the reference to change the value of whatever was passed in. This makes sense if you are passing x, y, because the code could conceivably update those values.

But in this case, changing the value of either x*2 or x+y does not make sense, the compiler insists that the reference be const.

Comment: Adding const is never a problem, i believe, its when you attempt to remove the const qualifier you run into trouble, right?

Oh but the error is if he REMOVES the const, right, nevermind

Comment: @DanF Adding `const` is a problem if you rely on being able to modify the referenced object.

Answer (score 1):

```
pair(const L& left,const R& right)
        : lft(left), rht(right)
{
}

pairDemo::pair<int, double> func(int x, double y) 
{
    pairDemo::pair<int, double> temp(x*2, x+y);
    return temp;                //   ^^^  ^^^
}                               //  temporaries here
```

Your constructor takes its parameters by reference. In `func`, you're passing temporary objects to this constructor. Temporary objects can only bind to *const* references, that's why you're getting an error if you remove `const`. If you chose to pass the parameters by value, you could omit const qualifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have a parameter of type `int &`, you cannot pass an argument `x * 2`. Having a non-const reference parameter allows modifications of the argument, and if you decide to ignore those modifications (if any), you need to do so explicitly.

As for passing `x * 2` to `const int &`, it may be a bit strange that that works, but what actually happens is that a new temporary variable is created, assigned `x * 2`, and *that* variable is what gets passed to the function. In this case, there isn't a problem with automatically creating a temporary, because its value won't be changed anyway (that's why you have `const`, is it not?).